# What is the closure of product loci in A_g?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, moduli-spaces

Let $A_g$ denote the moduli space of principally polarized abelian varieties of dimension $g$. For any partition of $g$, one can consider the corresponding locus inside $A_g$ of products of lower-dimensional abelian varieties.

My question is: can one describe explicitly the closure of this locus in (some) compactification?

I guess part of this question is what compactification one should use. For instance, if one simply chooses a toroidal compactification $\widetilde{A}_g$, one can also extend the universal family to a family of semistable abelian varieties. Can one describe necessary and sufficient conditions for a semistable abelian variety at the boundary for it to be in the closure of such a product locus? Or perhaps if one restricts attention to rank-one degenerations, so it does not depend on a choice of toroidal compactification?

Alternatively, one could choose a point in the closure of $A_g$ inside Alexeev's space of stable semi-abelic pairs -- are there necessary and sufficient conditions in this situation?

Comment: Of course a ppav in A(g) is a product iff its theta divisor is singular in codimension one.  Maybe that has a generalization to semi abelian varieties.

Comment: @roy smith: The most obvious generalization does not work.  The semi-abelic varieties of Alexeev are typically singular in codimension $1$, hence every Cartier divisor (e.g., the theta divisor) is singular in codimension $1$.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer, but perhaps a suggestion for where to get some ideas. Michael van Opstall studied moduli spaces of products of stable curves (of general type) in [this](http://www.springerlink.com/content/thl5cxn9x2cmjhv5/) and [this](http://www.springerlink.com/content/7580w477qu254t35/) papers. While his focus is on curves of genus $g>1$, some of the general deformation theoretic arguments might help you. Also, after all, a polarized abelian variety is of log general type, so possibly the arguments in this paper can be extended to pairs and then applied à la Alexeev.

Comment: The links to `springerlink.com` are broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshots saved on the Wayback Machine.